# How to test my service?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

That's my link: http://localhost:54483/BusinessService.svc/GetCustomers?numberOf=12&valid=true

Always getting the "Bad Request" error when executing at client site.
Stays at the startpage (you have created a service...)When entering the URL in the browser.

Following the method:

```
[ActionName("GetCustomers")]
[HttpGet]
public System.Collections.Generic.List<BusinessObjects.Customer> GetCustomers(byte numberOf, bool valid) {
    return BS.GetCustomers(byte numberOf, bool valid); //BS = BusinessService Instance
}
```

**EDIT**

That's my BusinessService Interface:

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContract]
System.Collections.Generic.List<BusinessObjects.Customer>   
GetCustomers(byte numberOf, bool valid);
```

Following the implementation of that method:

```
public virtual System.Collections.Generic.List<BusinessObjects.Customer> GetCustomers(byte numberOf, bool valid) {
    return this.BL.GetCustomers(byte numberOf, bool valid); //BL = BusinessLogic Instance
}
```

In my API:

```
[ActionName("GetCustomers")]
[HttpGet]
public System.Collections.Generic.List<BusinessObjects.Customer> GetCustomers(byte numberOf, bool valid) {
    return BS.GetCustomers(byte numberOf, bool valid); //BS = BusinessService Instance
}
```

**Web Config file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>

<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
</system.web>


<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="WcfService2.Service1">
    <endpoint address=""
              behaviorConfiguration=""
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="WcfService2.TestService" />
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="restBehavior">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>

      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>

      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>

<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>


<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78546/discussion-on-question-by-aj-83-how-to-test-my-service).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cover all my initial comments and convert them into one (hopefully) useful answer: I think you built your service having REST in mind, but WCF is SOAP by default and this confuses your clients.

There are a lot of articles around the web on how to enable REST in WCF, quick google search should get you where you want in no time. I shared this link already in the comments, but it could be useful if somebody needs it in the future: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/803409/REST-enabled-WCF-service#10.

Long story short - REST is not something you get straight out of the box with WCF.

Comment: There was something wrong with the project, changing the web config file was not enough. I had to create a new project, strange.

Answer (score 2):

I want to comment for this question but I must have 50 reputation to comment.

By default, WCF webservices only have SOAP protocol. If you want call it from browsers, you must enable RESTful.

You can follow [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571813/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Creating-WCF-REST-Services) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/255684/Create-and-Consume-RESTFul-Service-in-NET-Framewor) to enable RESTful.

Comment: Can you provide an web.config example please. I tried to change my config like the example, but the compiler is giving me errors. My web config is really messed up right now.

Comment: Just create a new project and copy the config from there.